# Commutative Algebra - Rings and Subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra

So, I'm doing some questions to understand the topic better and, for example, am proving that a subring of a commutative ring is also commutative, or that a subring of an integral domain is also an integral domain. So, assuming Ai is a subring of A:

I take two elements in Ai which have a property (so ab is not the same as ba in Ai, for example) then say that these are in the ring A and therefore the property must still hold, hence a contradiction. (If that makes sense)

What I was wondering is: Is it really justified to do that? Can I say that if a.b = 0 in Ai, then a.b = 0 in A, for example? I ask because I started to think about this and couldn't disprove the idea that there might exist some ring where it isn't true.
(I know what follows isn't correct, but it's trying to highlight my problem): For example, 2.3 = 6 which is 0 is Z/6Z, but if this contained in Z/12Z, then 2.3 = 6 and is no longer zero. I know this line is wrong! Please don't focus on it as it was just trying to highlight a point. My problem is rising because I can't think of a proof either way.

Comment: First, is there any reason you're calling the subring "Ai"? Second, "have a property" is really vague. Third, if $ab=0$ holds true in a subring then it holds true in the original ring. This is because the operations on the subring are inherited from the original ring - an equation holds true in the subring if and only if it holds true in the original ring. This kind of fact should be so obvious one doesn't even ask for a proof.

Comment: It's just the notation in the book! I realise that have a property may be vague, but now I've been reminded about the inclusion map, I can prove it for all the "vague properties" that I'm considering. So, sorry for that. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So given a subring $R\subset S$, consider the inclusion map $i:R\to S$. This map is injective, so $i(x)=i(y)\iff x=y$. Then in case 1, suppose $S$ is commutative.
$$
i(a\cdot_R b)=i(a)\cdot_S i(b)=i(b)\cdot_Si(a)=i(b\cdot_R a)\iff a\cdot_R b=b\cdot_R a.
$$
You can make a similar argument for the case of a domain. Suppose $a\cdot_R b=0_R$. Then
$$
a\cdot_S b=i(a\cdot_R b)=i(0_R)=0_S\implies i(a)=0_S\text{ or }i(b)=0_S\implies a=0_R\text{ or }b=0_R.
$$
The notation may be a little sketchy because I'm trying to be pedantic here, but does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense. As soon as you mentioned inclusion map, I understood. It was mentioned earlier in the chapter, but I'd forgotten about it. Thank you very much!

Comment: Great. It's difficult to denote when $a,b$ are lying in $R$ and $S$ since ... everything looks the same. But this proof happens just like a subgroup of an abelian group is abelian.